# Why wouldn't the Policy ability method get called?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have used the generator to generate a simple policy:

```
php artisan make:policy TeamPolicy
```

And, I have registered it in `AuthServiceProvider` as:

```
 protected $policies = [
        Team::class => TeamPolicy::class,
    ];
```

I tried to call it in the `TeamsController` as:

```
$this->authorize('update', $team);
```

Here is my policy file `Policies\TeamPolicy.php` as:

```
<?php
namespace App\Policies;
use App\Team;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;
class TeamPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;
    /**
     * Create a new policy instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }
    public function update( Team $team)
    {
        App:debug("Policy update called!");
        return true;
    }
}
```

However, the update method in the policy is never called, and I get error 403 when calling `$this->authorize('update', $team);`

Please advise!

Comment: how does your teamcontroler look like?

Comment: My TeamsController looks like any other regular controller. It has many methods including the edit and update methods which contains the call `$this->authorize('update', $team);` that outputs the error mentioned above.Unfortunately, I cannot share the specifics of the controller with anyone as it is confidential.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument of the Policy methods should be the user to check authorization on. Try instead:

```
public function update(User $user, Team $team)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: This does not fix anything.

Comment: @user7409342 Are you sure that the `$team` variable is an instance of `Team` class? How are you getting it?

Comment: I am instantiating the $team object from the Team class located in `app/Team.php`.

Comment: @user7409342 ok, then.. I don't know. If the AuthServiceProvider registers the policy correctly, and also the variable you are trying to authorize is an instance of the registered class, the policy method should definitely be called. I'd say double check all this. Like `dd($team)` and see 100% it's an instance of Team. Also, you have a user logged in, right?